# repositioning child div in responsive design

Tags: css, responsive-design

i've designed a page with a div and two child div, disposed in line. One left, one right.
I'd like to reposition the two child div in a responsive design. How can I do?

I've created the page with this HTML:

```
 <div id=contenitore class=clearfix>
<div class="imgsx"> Content </div>
<div class="txtdx"> Content.</div>
</div>
```

This is the CSS.

```
#contenitore {
    position:relative;  
}

.txtsx {
    width:60%;  
    float:left;
}
.imgdx {
    width:40%;  
    float:right;
```

As far it works well.

When I use a rule for responsive it doesn't work. My need is to put the div txtsx above the txtsx, full screen on mobile devices.

this is the CSS I've used:

```
 @media screen and (max-width: 60em)

#contenitore {
        clear: both;
        padding: 0px;
        margin: 0px;
    }

    .txtsx {
        width:100%; !important

    }
    .imgdx {
        width:100%; !important
```

Comment: Please can you make a fiddle

Comment: Yes, thank you: http://jsfiddle.net/MP3qP/

Answer (score 0):

Normal CSS float both on left...

```
#contenitore {
    position:relative;  
}

.txtsx {
    width:60%;  
    float:left;
}
.imgdx {
    width:40%;  
    float:left;
}
```

In query resize float them right

```
 @media screen and (max-width: 60em) {
     .imgdx, .txtsx {
          float:none;
          width:100%;
     }
}
```

Is what I think you're asking for...

Comment: I'm sorry but it doesn't work, could be a due to the 
 position:relative of the div?

Answer (score 0):

This does what you asked for:

CSS:

```
#contenitore {
    position:relative;
}
.imgsx {
    width: 60%;
    float: left;
}
.txtdx {
    width: 40%;
    float: right;
}
@media all and (max-width: 200px) {
    .txtdx, .imgsx {
        width: 100% !important;
    }
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Hive7/MP3qP/2/